# Удаление разряда из числа C#

Tags: c#

Как удалить из целого числа разряд, заданный номером? Например, дано число 123456. Человек вводит через консоль цифру 3. И получается результат 12356

Comment: Число -> строка -> удалить символ -> обратно в число

Comment: не понимаю, как это сделать на проге

Comment: А прошлая ветка вас ничему не научила?

Comment: У меня получилось все: добавление, перенос и т.д. А удаление не принимает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну в данном случае же ещё проще:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите позицию");
int s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int m = 1;
while (s > 1) {
     m *= 10;
     s--;
}
int t = (x % m) + (x / (m * 10)) * m;
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

Comment: Вы правы, это было просто, спасибо

Comment: я Вас наверное уже достала)) в Вашей программе у меня не получается, например, вставить число. я добавила Console.WriteLine("Введите число, которое хотите вставить") и т.п. Но не догоняю, как подставить в формулу в итоге(( помогите мне в последний раз, пожалуйста, и я пойду читать книжки по программированию самостоятельно:) (Это уже для себя просто, пытаюсь разобраться)

Comment: @Maria просто скопируйте весь код из этого ответа себе в метод `Main` и всё заработает. Я проверил.

Comment: @Maria Вы спрашиваете уже о какой-то другой задаче. Строка с t выполняет вычисление двух частей числа и их сдвижку. Вам же, вероятно, понадобится раздвинуть части, изменив правый член и добавив ещё один.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо, я научилась вставлять значения тоже)

Answer (score 2):

```
        int number = 123456;
        int delete = 3;
        var str = number.ToString();
        number = int.Parse(str.Remove(str.Length - delete, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8
Метод string.Remove(номер индекса удаляемого символа, кол-во удаляемых символов после индекса)

```
int prevNum = 123456;
string tmpNum = prevNum.ToString().Remove(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), 1);
int aftNum = int.Parse(tmpNum);
```